# How can I turn an odd number even, or vice versa, in Motorola 68000 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, 68000, easy68k

Basically if I had a number in D1, and wanted it to ALWAYS be even, how would I make sure it is never odd?

I know it has something to do with the AND instruction. But when I tried that, it would always subtract 1. So it would turn odd numbers even and even numbers odd.

How can I basically do `if n is odd, sub 1`

Comment: *So it would turn odd numbers even and even numbers odd*: AND can't set bits, only clear them or leave them set, so it can't make an even number odd.  So your attempt with AND must have had a bug that made it do something else.  (XOR with 1 would flip the low bit, flipping between odd and even.  So would ADD 1, but that would carry into high bits.)  Anyway, hopefully with these answers + the debugger built in to easy68k you can sort out what you actually did.

Comment: *"... AND instruction. But when I tried that, it would always subtract 1."* - that's literally impossible. If you really believe into this, you should try to produce [MCVE] of that, but you should figure out yourself the `and` does not **always** subtract 1 (for example `(12 and 254) = 12` ... only cases like `(13 and 254) = 12` may look like subtraction of 1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and` your number with `-2`.

In 2's complement representation -2 is a number with all bits set to one except the lowest one (11111...110), so, used as a mask, it always kills just the low bit of your number. This forces it to be even (it works correctly even for negative numbers).

---

As for the "viceversa" in the title: to do the opposite (=force every even number to the next odd), just `or` with `1`. This sets the low bit to be 1, which obtains the required effect.

Answer (score 4):

Odd numbers end with `1` in binary, and even numbers end with `0` in binary. What you really want is to make the last binary digit be `0`, regardless of what it started as. (That'll subtract 1 from odd numbers, and leave even numbers unchanged.)

The way to do this is to AND with `1111...1110`, where all binary digits are `1` except the last digit, which is `0`. You can construct this by doing a bitwise negation on `0000...0001`, which of course is just `1`.

So if your number is `n`, you want to compute `n & (~1)`.

Answer (score 3):

The 68000 CPU actually has separate bit set and bit clear commands. In cases like yours, it might be simpler and clearer to explicitly clear bit 0 of the operand without reverting to boolean logic:

```
bclr.l #0,d0
```

instead of

```
and.l $fffffffe,d0
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to clear the bottom bit, so whilst others have used long word instructions, there's nothing wrong with using the byte form of AND

```
AND.B #0xFE, D1   ; make even
OR.B  #0x01, D1   ; make odd
XOR.B #0x01, D1   ; toggle even/odd
```

No matter what the size of the value in D1 (byte, word or longword), you've still cleared the bottom bit and left all the other bits in the register unchanged

Alternatively

```
BCLR #0,D1  ; make even
BSET #0,D1  ; make odd
BCHG #0,D1  ; toggle even/odd
```

Answer (score 1):

For a 16 Bit Number do this:

```
EvenNumber = (D1 & 0xFFFE);
```